# SpringBoot + Auth0 - CORS Problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors, auth0

Even after configuring everything according to the docs, i'm still having sobe CORS issues while trying to do some operations on my site.

I'm making an YouTube clone using a tutorial. So far so good, i managed to cover and adapt the parts in there that weren't working \ were deprecated (this includes the use of filterChain instead of WebSecurityConfigureAdpter on SecurityConfig.java).

However, when i try to request an endpoint (for uploading the videos), the moment i click the upload button i receive a 401 XHR error - related to cross origin issues.

On my SecurityConfig.java everything looks setup correctly. On the WebMvc config also, allowing anything from everywhere.

I've tried to implement a function inside SecurityConfig.java as a Bean, to configure cors separatedly (without the WebMvcConfig class) but it didn't worked also. I'm kinda lost here.

This projects runs angular  in the FrontEnd. I added a small part to identify if the user was logged in (just showing user details after login), and the user is authenticated (after logging in i can display the user details).

Any input would be appreciated. Also, if i missed anything here in order to describe my problem, i'll be glad to edit the post and provide the information.

Thanks in advance!

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer.uri}")
    private String issuer;
    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();

        return http.build();



    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "content-type"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "content-type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

WebMvcConfig.java
package com.pablo.portfolio.youtubeclone.config;

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration

public class WebMvcConfig  implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry){
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .maxAge(3600);

    }
}
```

VideoController.java

```
package com.pablo.portfolio.youtubeclone.controller;


@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/videos")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class VideoController {

    private final VideoService videoService;


    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public UploadVideoResponse uploadVideo(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file){
        return videoService.uploadVideo(file);

    }
    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/thumbnail")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String uploadThumbnail
            (@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("videoId") String videoId){
        return videoService.uploadThumbnail(file, videoId);
    }
    @CrossOrigin
    @PutMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public VideoDto editVideoMetaData(@RequestBody VideoDto videoDto){
        return videoService.editVideo(videoDto);
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/{videoId}")
    public VideoDto getVideoDetails(@PathVariable String videoId){
        return videoService.getVideoDetails(videoId);
    }

}
```

EDIT:
I noticed the following information on my log:

```
2023-04-09T18:13:20.032-03:00 DEBUG 1197563 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/videos
2023-04-09T18:13:20.045-03:00 DEBUG 1197563 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
```

Maybe it isn't loading the correct authentication filter?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set your `CorsConfiguration` to allow credentials. Here's what I have in Kotlin. It works without any additional Spring Boot configuration.

```kotlin
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource

@Configuration
class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun webSecurity(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        ...

        http.cors()
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        val config = CorsConfiguration()
        config.allowCredentials = true
        config.allowedOrigins = listOf("http://localhost:4200")
        config.allowedMethods = listOf("*")
        config.allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)
        return source
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the documentation from Auth0 and rebuilt my filterChain. After that, i fixed the cors problem i suppose (since now i can see trough Inttelij log that requests are being received and authorized). However, when i try to save something there's an CSRF error (Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/api/videos), Trying to debug\understand.

Comment: If you're not serving up any server-rendered pages, you likely don't need CSRF and can disable it with `http.csrf().disable()`. If you'd still like to use it, you'll need to set a CSRF cookie and read it/send it as a header on the client side. This article shows you how to do that with React and Spring Boot: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/06/17/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I'm also making a youtube clone with React Native/JSX.

Looks like you're using Java but I also got the same error when trying to implement. I was using RapidAPI's youtube API.

- verify the server permissions
- check the server logs
- verify the software version
- test the endpoints with Postman or on the site
- restart/re-install packages

Comment: Im considering restart the project. I was able to test everything with  postman (managed to get the token, update video details, etc). But trough the browser there are issues. I fought I had problems with http interceptor but it’s fine also. I can also view the token on inspect/network tab.